# How to give border line to single td element in the table tr element?

Tags: asp.net, css, user-controls

I have a table in ASP.Net like this.

```
 <table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td rowspan="4" colspan="2" class="style1">
     </td>                                        
     <td>
         <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Label1"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="136px">
         </asp:TextBox>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>        
    <td><asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text="Label2"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="136px">
         </asp:TextBox></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>        
    <td><asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" Text="Label3"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="136px">
         </asp:TextBox></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>        
    <td><asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" Text="Label4"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="136px">
         </asp:TextBox></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

I want to give border line to first td element which contains the colspan and rowspan. Not to the entire row.
Please give solution.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? And what was the result?

Comment: @Spiny. I used a style sheet and included that in the <td> element tag. like .border{ border-color:black; border-style:solid; } But I want a thin line as a border. I tried all other options I couldn't get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want border only on the td with class *style1* :

```
table, tr, td { border: none; }
td.style1 { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try jquery http://jquery.com/

Add this in your head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then add this in the body

```
<script> 
$('table tr td:first').css('border','1px solid');
<script/>
```

Comment: I followed what u have said, but it doesn't produce the desired result. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Try this $('.style1').css('border','1px solid'); By the way do you need a black border?

Answer (score 2):

Set this style on the td:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .firsttd { border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; }
</style>

...

<td class="firsttd" rowspan="4" colspan="2" >
```

Comment: Yes. But Border should be a very thin line. I have tried all the other options given. But I couldn't get.